# Sequelize loop of findOne queries

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables A and B. The scenario is that I run an array over a loop to use those entries in a findOne query on table A before inserting into table B. Even if one item from the array does not exist in table A the operation should fail. What I have now is as follows

```
var idList = [1,2,3,4,5];
for (i=0; i<idList.length; i++){
  await A.findOne({ where: { id : i }}).then((product) => {
    if(!product){
      notValidItem.push(i);
    }
  });
  if (notValidItem.length > 0){
    return res.status(400).send({ message : 'Invalid Operation' });
  }
  else{
    next();
    //going ahead with inserting into table B
  }
}
```

The above method works for sure... but do we have a more lamda or a function oriented implementation instead of the loop in the above code? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: why don't you call DB only once with `where: {id: idList }` making as `WHERE id IN (...)`

Comment: well that ensures that i have entries with ids matching with atleast one of the array item. But i need to match with every one of the items in the array

Comment: I'm only saying that because it's very "expensive" (in terms of resources and time) to call the DB so many times, it's easier to fetch once and then check what id's you are missing... imagine if you have 20 items in that array... it can take 200ms each call to the DB, will take you 5ms to checks what items you are missing in an array

Comment: Don't mix `await` and `then`. In this case I'd prefer `await`

Comment: And for sure It's useless to get objects one by one.  Fetch'em all together and then compare with initial array of ids by creating a dictionary for instance

Comment: Yup makes sense... thanks for the inputs lemme answer with them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution with Promises would be to use Promise.all() . If any of those Promises fail, you'll get an Error.

```
try {
    let idList = [1,2,3,4,5];
    let promisesArray = [];
    for (i=0; i<idList.length; i++){
        promisesArray.push(A.findOne({ where: { id : i }}))
    }
    await Promise.all(promisesChangeMenuOrder);
    next();
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error) // don't console.log errors in production
    return res.status(400).send({ message : 'Invalid Operation' });
}
```

Next solution would be:

```
let rows = A.findAll({
    where: {
        id: [1,2,3,4,5]
    }
})
```

And now check if length is what it should be and if non of those values is null. This is much better solution I think...

Comment: Still that makes like 5 seperate db calls right?

Comment: That's why the second method is better... It's 1 call.

Answer (score 0):

Since ive got an advantage that the array items and items from database are going to be unique the following method worked for me

```
var idList = [1,2,3,4,5];
A.findAll({ where: { id : { [Op.in] : idList }}}).then((foundItems) => {
  foundItemsArray = foundItems.map((x) =>  x.id);
  diffence = idList.filter(x => !foundItemsArray.includes(x));
  if(diffence.length > 0){
    //failure here              
  }
  else{
    next();
  }
})
```